# ArrayList of string arrays and iteration, adding, updating or removing values

Tags: java, arraylist

Start my questions by showing my problem in a code to save time reading.
issues:

-Can't save string[] with 3 values in an ArrayList properly.

-Can't change the value of an array in a ArrayList.

```
List<String> objects= new ArrayList<String>();

//creates an object to be saved in an arrayList which it will be printed to a file.
custFile(long ID, int acc, String trans) 
{

String customer = bank.infoCustomer(iD);
String account = Integer.toString(acc); //bank.infoAccount(iD, acc);
String transactions;

if(trans == "")
{            
transactions = "\nNo transactions made\n";
}                    
else  transactions ="\nTransactions : " + trans;

//My string array with three values.
String[] obj = {customer, account, transactions};

if(!objects.isEmpty())       
{

int n = objects.size();          
int p = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < objects.subList(p, n).size(); i++)           
{                
if(!objects.listIterator(i).equals(obj))                 
{
objects.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj));
return; //needed?
}                
else
{
//Remove in order to update
objects.remove(i);

//Add to the List                
objects.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj)); 
}           
}
else
//Add String[] the first time and only time.             
objects.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj));
```

When I remove a string (with the three values) from the ArrayList, two weird couple of lines containing the third value of the string are left behind:
//This

0

//And this

Transactions : null

I've tried different methods to add and remove and iterate over the ArrayList but nothing seems to work.

Adding: repeats the string value.

Removing: works half the way.

Iterating: won't give me the exact element to be compared or removed.

My String[] obj = {customer, account, transactions}; once I print it looks like this:

//Customer

3 : c

//Account(s)

Account Type:
Saving Account 1005

Balance: 0.0

Account Type:
Credit Account 1006

Balance: 0.0

//Transactions

0

Transactions : null

And the ArrayList contains many strings with similar values(three: customer, account, transactions)

It should be possible to update the objects using this method I believe.

Little push I'll be grateful.

Comment: Don't you have a typo here: `String customer = bank.infoCustomer(iD);` .  Shouldn't it be `ID` instead of `iD`?

Comment: Oh that is not affecting the result at all. Id is being sent and received also printed without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear.  What I can tell you is that if you're iterating over an arraylist it's difficult to remove items mid-loop.

ex) if i = 2 and you remove the 2nd element in the arraylist, your 3rd element is now referenced by 2, but your for loop counter will increment to 3 before checking the arraylist again

As an aside: Object.equals is not implemented, and so when you call object.equals, you're just checking to see that they are the SAME object.  In other words, you're comparing the two pointers

Comment: Hard to understand what was going on myself so I did what I could when trying to explain it. Mid-loop, should I just check if true/false and remove it outside? Implement the Object.equals I have tried but without results. There are many things I've tried that I did not put in my question.

Comment: Here is what I suspect: I might be saving values of string arrays in the wrong array list and I might not been implementing the objects.get(i).equals.. the right way. And, I might be lost when removing an array of strings inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not fix the problem above I found an interesting short cut to my goal. This is how I manage:

Instead of having a string array with three values(customer, account, transactions) I created a string with one value. The class account Saving and class account Credit has access to transaction method from class Account where Saving and Credit inherit. The bank logic responsible for the objects has a method where customer is fetched with all its values coming from a Map; Map < Account, Customer> customerInfo = new HashMap < Account, Customer>(); . In other words here is the seudo:

add transactions to account.

add account to customer.

add customer to list.

Here is my new custFile method.

//List array with string values.
List objects= new ArrayList();

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Description: A method that creates and updates a list Array. The update works by choosing the first   
 //              characters of the input and the existing string in the list and comparing them
 //              removing if equals and adding the last input containing the new values for the 
 //              string. Adding a new string object otherwise.
 // Arguments: Long for Id customer to be created or updated in the list.
 // Return: An array list with the current database.
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 public void custFile(long iD) //, int acc, String trans )
 {       
     String customer = bank.infoCustomer(iD);

     System.out.println("\n\n\n" + "     String with three values" + "\n\n\n");
     System.out.println(customer + "");
     System.out.println("\n\n" + "      End" + "\n\n");  

     if(!objects.isEmpty())
     {                       
             System.out.println("\n4");         
             boolean exist= false;
             String custToRem = null;
             for(int i = 0; i< objects.size(); i++)
             {
                 //A few prints to make sure the values are equals.
                 System.out.println("1\n");
                 System.out.println("1a\n");
                 System.out.println(objects.get(i).substring(0, 5));
                 System.out.println("1b\n");
                 System.out.println(customer.substring(0, 5));
                 System.out.println("1c\n");

                 if(objects.get(i).substring(0,5).equals(customer.substring(0, 5))) //&& objects.get(i).substring(1, 20).equals(customer.substring(1, 20)))
                 {
                     System.out.println("2 Deleting");
                     custToRem = objects.get(i);
                     System.out.println(custToRem);
                     System.out.println("3 Deleted");
                     exist = true;   
                 }
                 else
                     exist = false;
             }
             if(exist = true)
             {               
                 System.out.println("4");
                 System.out.println(custToRem);
                 objects.remove(custToRem);
                 objects.add(customer);
                 System.out.println("5");
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("6");
                 objects.add(custToRem);
                 System.out.println("7");
             }
             System.out.println(objects.toString());         
        }           
     else
         objects.add(customer); 
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Description: A method that removes a value from the list Array. This by searching throughout the 
 //              list for an identical value.
 // Arguments: Long for Id customer to be remove from the list array.
 // Return: None.
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public void removeObj(long iD)
 {

     String obj = String.valueOf(iD);
     System.out.println("remove fr GUI, iD: " +  obj);

     String customer = bank.infoCustomer(iD); 

     Iterator<String> itr = objects.iterator();

     String element = "";

     while(itr.hasNext())
     {
         element = (String) itr.next();
         if(element.contains(customer))
         {
             itr.remove();
             System.out.println("\n\nitr removed, from removeObj() -GUI ");
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```